# Insert data into MongoDb using mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of strings, I want to map through this array and update my collection with it's values.

This is What I have tried:

```
 if (employees) {
      employees.map((employee) => {
        Employee.updateOne({ $push: { name: employee.name } })
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
          });
      });
    }
```

At the top I am importing my model :

```
const Employee = require('../../models/employees');
```

My Model looks like this :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
});

const Employee = mongoose.model('employee', EmployeeSchema);

module.exports = Employee;
```

My console is logging the next :

```
{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

But when i check the database the data is not there and no collection is created.

Comment: Are you trying to update or insert documents in the collection? It seems that you want to insert/create documents.

Comment: @Yousaf I worded it wrongly. I am trying to insert/create

Comment: Take a look at: [Document.prototype.save()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-save) and [Model.create()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.create). You can use one of these methods to create documents.

Answer (score 0):

`updateOne` has [following syntax](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateOne).

1. First parameter is `condition/filter`.
2. Second parameter is `doc` to be updated.
3. Third is `options`. Where you need to pass `upsert` to true.

**Note**: If `upsert` is set to `true` then `updateOne` will create new `doc` if the `filter` results empty.

```js
const insertEmployees = () => {
  try {
    if (employees) {
      employees.map(async employee => {
        let filter = { name: employee.name }
        let doc = { $push: { name: employee.name } }
        let options = { upsert: true }
        await Employee.updateOne(filter, doc, options)
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```